# Как работает для списка [1:]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Если мой код выглядит так:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

s = l[1:]
```

То `s` — это все еще ссылка на `l`, которая читает его по правилу `[1:]`, или же создался новый список `l = [2, 3, 4]`, значение которого присвоили `s`?

Comment: Это именно копия, даже есть такой рецепт делания копии списка - взять от него полный срез `[:]`

Comment: @CrazyElf, это копия ссылок на элементы списка )

Comment: @MaxU Если быть совсем точным, то да )

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ну есть же два типа копий: поверхностная (shallow) и глубокая (deep). Просто правильно употребляйте термины, господа, тогда не будет разночтений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле это интересный и непростой вопрос. Когда вы создаете срез, Python создает копии **ссылок** на элементы списка:

```
In [58]: l = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]

In [59]: s = l[1:]

In [60]: [id(x) for x in l]
Out[60]: [140412420854224, 140412420857168, 140412420854032, 140412420857648]

In [61]: [id(x) for x in s]
Out[61]: [140412420857168, 140412420854032, 140412420857648]
```

с первого взгляда может показаться, что `s` - это ссылка на `l[1:]`, но если изменить один из элементов в `s` - это не изменит данные в исходном `l`:

```
In [62]: s[0] += 111

In [63]: s
Out[63]: [2111, 3000, 4000]

In [64]: l
Out[64]: [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
```

---

если копнуть глубже и использовать список списков - ситуация кардинально изменится - обратите внимание на измененный элемент в исходном подсписке `ll`, после того как мы изменили элемент в подсписке `ss`:

```
In [65]: ll = [[1000, 1000], [2000, 2000]]

In [66]: ss = ll[1:]

In [67]: ss[0][0] += 111

In [68]: ll
Out[68]: [[1000, 1000], [2111, 2000]]

In [69]: ss
Out[69]: [[2111, 2000]]
```

но `id` все еще совпадают:

```
In [70]: [id(x) for x in ll]
Out[70]: [140411607786432, 140413521522240]

In [71]: [id(x) for x in ss]
Out[71]: [140413521522240]
```

Answer (score 2):

это отдельный объект (срез)

вы можете проверить это следующим кодом

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

s = l[1:]

l[1] = 7

print(l) # 1, 7, 3, 4
print(s) # 2, 3, 4 а не 7, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего проверить, тот же это объект или нет - посмотреть его `id`.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = l
s = l[1:]

print("l id =", id(l))
print("x id =", id(x), "  x тот же что l :", id(x) == id(l))
print("s id =", id(s), "  s тот же что l :", id(s) == id(l))
```

```
l id = 139671557991232
x id = 139671557991232   x тот же что l : True
s id = 139671557937824   s тот же что l : False
```

Comment: я все таки здесь оставлю ссылку на [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), так как для новичков не очевидно и не всегда ясно использование `id()`. Для ленивых - возвращает объект идентификации, целое число. Из реализации на CPython - адрес объекта в памяти. За деталями читайте ссылку

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего это внести изменения и посмотреть, что происходит

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
s = l[1:]

s.append(10)
print(l, s)
[1, 2, 3, 4] [2, 3, 4, 10]
```

то есть `s` не ссылается больше на `l` и изменения `s` не привносят изменения в `l`

Ну и что в говорит [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

> list.copy()
> Return a shallow copy of the list. Equivalent to a[:].

То есть, создается копия части родительского списка